# Is it raining? I can't tell

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

These are raindrops:

```
! | . " :
```

These are clouds particles:

```
( ) _ @ $ &
```

I want you to verify, when given a block of text, whether or not it is raining. It is raining if, for every raindrop, there is a cloud particle somewhere above it. There must be one cloud particle for every raindrop. Output a [truthy or falsy value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) denoting your conclusions.

## Valid examples

```
(@@@@@@)
 ( $ &  )
Q   (  )
..  .  !
 : .
  |"   !
    .
```

```
()()()
......
```

```
@_$ &
errrr
h_r-5
.:. .
 "
```

## Invalid examples

```
!
()
```

```
$$$$$
(   )
:::::
.....
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest program in *characters* wins.

Comment: "There must be one cloud particle for every raindrop"

Comment: @feersum The second invalid example is the example you are looking for.

Comment: @feersum I see ;)

Comment: Can we assume the rows are padded with spaces to form a rectangle?

Comment: @feersum yeah you can

Comment: So, exactly one cloud particle for each raindrop particle `:-(`

Comment: @Zereges, no: at least one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## APL (30)

```
{∧/∊≤/+⍀¨⍵∘∊¨'!|.":' '()_@$&'}
```

This is a function that takes a character matrix as input, and gives a boolean output.

Test:

```
      ex1 ex2 ex3 ex4 ex5
┌─────────┬──────┬─────┬──┬─────┐
│(@@@@@@) │()()()│@_$ &│! │$$$$$│
│ ( $ &  )│......│errrr│()│(   )│
│Q   (  ) │      │h_r-5│  │:::::│
│..  .  ! │      │.:. .│  │.....│
│ : .     │      │ "   │  │     │
│  |"   ! │      │     │  │     │
│    .    │      │     │  │     │
└─────────┴──────┴─────┴──┴─────┘
      {∧/∊≤/+⍀¨⍵∘∊¨'!|.":' '()_@$&'}¨ex1 ex2 ex3 ex4 ex5
1 1 1 0 0
```

Explanation:

- `⍵∘∊¨'!|.":' '()_@$&'`: for both sets of characters (rain and clouds), and each character in ⍵, see if the character is a member of the set.
- `+⍀¨`: get a running sum for each column and each set
- `≤/`: for each position in ⍵, check that the amount of raindrops does not exceed the amount of cloud particles in the running sum
- `∧/∊`: return the boolean AND of all the elements in the result

Answer (score 5):

## C++11, <s>186</s> 184 bytes

```
#include<map>
int i,c;int main(){std::map<int,int>p;while(~(c=getchar())){for(int m:{40,41,95,64,36,38})p[i]+=c==m;for(int m:{33,124,46,34,58})if(c==m&&!p[i]--)return 1;i=c-10?i+1:0;}}
```

Ungolfed

```
#include <map>
int i, c;
int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> p;
    while (~(c = getchar()))
    {
//        for (int m : { '(', ')', '_', '@', '$', '&'})
        for (int m : { 40, 41, 95, 64, 36, 38})
            p[i] += c == m;
//        for (int m : { '!', '|', '.', '"', ':'})
        for (int m : { 33, 124, 46, 34, 58})
            if (c == m && !p[i]--)
                return 1;
        i = c - '\n' ? i + 1 : 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basic approach, storing positions of cloud particles in a row and if rain particle is encountered, it checks whether the cloud particle is above it and decreases the counter of cloud particles in that column. The program returns 0 if it's valid and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Can't you replace `c-m?0:p[i]++` with `p[i]+=c==m`? Or does that no longer work in C++11?

Comment: @marinus Probably yes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Snails](https://github.com/feresum/PMA), 125

```
{t.{t(\(|\)|\_|\@|\$|\&)=(u.,~)d!(.,~)t.!(.,~},!{t(\!|\||\.|\"|\:)ud!(.,~}t(\(|\)|\_|\@|\$|\&)!(d.,~)u.,~},!{t(\!|\||\.|\"|\:
```

The program outputs the area of the grid (or 1 if its area is 0) if it is raining; otherwise 0. If only I had implemented regex-style character classes.

**Ungolfed version**
This contains fake instructions for clouds or raindrops instead of writing out all the gibberish. `\whatever` (replaced with `.` in the real program) means a thing that ought to be a raindrop, but can actually be anything because it doesn't matter if we match a non-raindrop to a cloud.

```
{
    t \whatever   ,, Pick a drop in a new column
    {
        t \cloud ,, Find a cloud with 
        =(u.,~)  ,, nothing above in the same column marked
        !(d.,~)  ,, but not in an empty column
        t \whatever
        !(d.,~)
    },
    !(t \drop ud !(.,~) )  ,,no drops remaining in column
    t \cloud
    !(d.,~)
    u.,~
},             ,, repeated 0 or more times
! (t \drop)   ,, no drops left
```

Comment: interesting comment system.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 121 bytes

```
def f(i):
 for l in zip(*i.split('\n')):
  s=0
  for p in l:
   s+=p in'()_@$&';s-=p in'!|.":'
   if s<0:return
 return 1
```

Expects the input to be padded to be rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 90 characters

```
s->all(cumsum(map(i->i∈"!|.\":"?-1:i∈"()_@\$&",mapfoldl(collect,hcat,split(s,"
")))').>-1)
```

Unlike the original solution (below), this uses mathematics to determine the solution. `mapfoldl(collect,hcat,split(s,"\n"))` (written above with `\n` replaced with an actual newline to save characters) converts the string into a 2d array of characters. `map(i->i∈"!|.\":"?-1:i∈"()_@\$&",...)` creates an array of numbers, with 1 if the character is a cloud, -1 if the character is rain, and 0 otherwise.

`cumsum(...')` calculates the cumulative sums of the rows (would normally be written `cumsum(...,2)`, but since we don't care about orientation from this point on, transposing only costs one character), and then `all(... .>-1)` checks for a negative number - negatives will only occur if a rain character appears without being preceded by a cloud character.

### Julia, <s>139</s> 136 *characters*

```
s->(t=join(mapfoldl(i->split(i,""),.*,split(s,"
")),"
");while t!=(t=replace(t,r"[()_@$&](.*?)[!|.\":]",s"\g<1>"))end;∩("!|.\":",t)==[])
```

This function first transposes the text so that rows become columns and vice-versa. Note that newlines are present in the code in the form of actual newlines, to save one character per instance.

The function then iteratively replaces cloud/droplet pairs with spaces, and once all such pairs are removed, it returns true if there are any droplets remaining and false otherwise.

`r"[()_@$&](.*?)[!|.\":]"` - this is a regex that will match cloud/droplet pairs in a lazy manner, with group 1 containing everything between cloud and droplet. Then `s"\g<1>"` tells it to remove the matched cloud and droplets, but keep the stuff in between (necessary as it may contain clouds) - the `\g<1>` is whatever was matched in group 1 of the regex. `∩("!|.\":",t)==[]` will generate the intersection of the droplet characters with the final string, and if it's empty, then none of the droplet characters are present, and it's raining.

Comment: @nimi - you don't actually need it. You can replace the `h` in the use with the actual anonymous function. Like this: `g((s->join(foldl(.*,[split(i,"")for i=split(s,"\n")]),"\n")s->join(foldl(.*,[split(i,"")for i=split(s,"\n")]),"\n"))("()()()\n......"))` - calling it `h` just makes it easier to invoke.

Comment: @nimi - as for the "single function to call", that's a slightly more reasonable assertion, but it's not clear what the community standing on that is - I'm going to make a meta post asking about it.

Comment: @nimi - that's what I'm going to get clarification on, right now, with a meta post.

Comment: It's moot for this question now, as I found a better way to do it, with only one function.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5, 80

79, plus one for `-E` instead of `-e`

```
@a=();while(<>){@_=split'';(0>($a[$_]+=/[()_@&\$]/-/[!|.":]/)?die:1)for@_}say 1
```

Comment: I can't read Perl, but I'm strong in math: 79+1 = 80

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 112

Test running the snippet below in an EcmaScript 6 compliant browser implementing arrow functions, spread operator and template strings (I use Firefox)

```js
f=t=>!t.split`
`.some(r=>[...r].some((c,i)=>(c='!|.":()_@$&'.indexOf(c),n[i]=~c?c<5?~-n[i]:-~n[i]:n[i])<0),n=[])

//TEST
console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n';

test_valid = [
 '(@@@@@@)\n ( $ &  )\nQ   (  )\n..  .  !\n : .\n  |"   !\n    .',
 '()()()\n......',
 '@_$ &\nerrrr\nh_r-5\n.:. .\n "'
] 
console.log('Valid');
test_valid.forEach(t=>console.log(t+'\n'+f(t)+'\n'))

test_invalid = ['!\n()','$$$$$\n(   )\n:::::\n.....']
console.log('Invalid');
test_invalid.forEach(t=>console.log(t+'\n'+f(t)+'\n'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```